# Magento 2: Add button next to "Shopping Cart" title

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, custom-button

When viewing my shopping cart there is an header "Shopping Cart", looks like this:

[image: shopping cart title]

**How can I add an button (or just a "a href link which has div inside it" would also be good enough) in that header part?**

**For example I would like to get "Continue shopping" which redirects to homepage when pressed.**

In the end I want something like this:

[image: result]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override 
**vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml** file in your active theme and update it like below.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $cssClass ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getId() ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria() ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    <?php if($block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) == "Shopping Cart") { ?><span><button>MyButton</button></span> <?php } ?> 
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Let me know if any further help needed.